# You must install or update .NET to run this application - error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-sdk

I'm trying to install .net try to learn LINQ with 101 LINQ samples. I've followed instructions on github page: https://github.com/dotnet/try-samples#basics, however when i try to run

```
dotnet run
```

in my terminal, i get this error:

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /Users/bulatpochanov/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-try
Architecture: arm64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' (arm64)
.NET location: /usr/local/share/dotnet

The following frameworks were found:
  6.0.21 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  7.0.9 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  7.0.10 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=arm64&rid=osx.12-arm64
```

I've tried installing version 3.1.0 framework, but then i get this error:

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /Users/bulatpochanov/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-try
Architecture: arm64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '7.0.10' (arm64)
.NET location: /usr/local/share/dotnet

The following frameworks were found:
  3.1.0 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=arm64&rid=osx.12-arm64
```

I've then tried to configure roll-forward behavior to make to application work with the newer version of .net as it states in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-discovery/troubleshoot-app-launch?pivots=os-windows#configure-roll-forward-behavior
However you need to specify the file when running `dotnet --roll-forward Major specifiedFile` which gets me confused as `dotnet try` should open a browser window with all the LINQ samples.

If it helps here is the video from microsoft channel how `dotnet try` should work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5myHVOtmiU

Comment: What version of the .NET SDK does the project you're trying to run require?

Comment: The linked GitHub page says to use .NET Core32.0. This is very very much unsafe (has been out of support without security fixes for years). A better start9ing point would be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/get-started.

Comment: I would suggest forking the repository and then updating your local copy to target .NET 6 (or 7) instead.

Comment: it doesn't specify anywhere what .NET SDK is required, i only figured it has to be 3.1.0 because of an error message

Comment: If you edit the .csproj file, you should see something like `<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>`. The specific value tells you which version.